# How to merge two object of rest api in django rest framwork?

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

This my views.py file

```
class NewsChannelListView(ObjectMultipleModelAPIView):

    def get_querylist(self, *args, **kwargs):
        userId = self.request.user.id
        queryset = [
            {'queryset': News_Channel.objects.all(),
             'serializer_class': NewsChannelSerializers},
            {'queryset': Count.objects.filter(userId=userId),
             'serializer_class': CountSerializers},
        ]
        return queryset
```

I am getting following respose from my this views

```
{
    "News_Channel": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Republic",
            "info": "Arnab Goswami News channel",
            "image": "https://fourthpillar-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/repiblic_1bRFWNZ.png",
            "website": "https://www.repu",
            "total_star": 10,
            "total_user": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "NDTV",
            "info": "India News Media",
            "image": "https://fourthpillar-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/ndtv_WH67OhA.png",
            "website": "https://ndtv.com",
            "total_star": 18,
            "total_user": 2
        }
    ],
    "Count": [
        {
            "userId": 1,
            "channelId": 2,
            "rate": 6
        },
        {
            "userId": 1,
            "channelId": 1,
            "rate": 8
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way I can get single object.Channel id 2 in count merge with the id 2 in news channel and Channel id 1 in count merge with the id 1 in news channel. So final Response shoule be like this

```
{
    "News_Channel": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Republic",
            "info": "Arnab Goswami News channel",
            "image": "https://fourthpillar-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/repiblic_1bRFWNZ.png",
            "website": "https://www.repu",
            "total_star": 10,
            "total_user": 2,
            "userId": 1,
            "rate": 6
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "NDTV",
            "info": "India News Media",
            "image": "https://fourthpillar-static.s3.amazonaws.com/media/ndtv_WH67OhA.png",
            "website": "https://ndtv.com",
            "total_star": 18,
            "total_user": 2,
            "userId": 1,
            "rate": 8
        }
    ],
}
```

Code of the model

```
class News_Channel(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=False)
    info = models.TextField(blank=False)
    image = models.FileField()
    website = models.TextField()
    total_star = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    total_user = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-id"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Count(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    channelId = models.ForeignKey(News_Channel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rate = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-id"]
```

I am using django 2.1.7 and the djangorestframework==3.9.2.

Comment: You should've used the normal DRF view at this case....I think\

Comment: also, you could override the **`format_results()`** method of the view class

Comment: Could you please share some stuff related to this or can modify the view in answer.

Comment: You might be able to use an `annotate()` call and then a `SerializerMethodField` to show it in the `NewsChannelSerializer` class. If you post your models, I can help with that.

Comment: @schillingt done. Please check model now in the question. Thanks for your response

Comment: How would the data be handled if there are 2 or more `Count` instances for the same `News_Channel`? Does `rate` get summed? Should there be multiple instances in the `News_Channel` list?

Comment: I have used a filter for userID. There will be an only a single Count instance for the new channel for a give user.

Comment: @imsaiful did you managed to merge? If yes, itd be great if you could share the solution. Thank you.